# Purpose of 'e1' in JavaScript Functions

Tags: javascript, function

I have a very simple and basic question and I'm kind of ashamed to ask it here but I can't find an answer anywhere else without going through hours of JS tutorials.

```
document.addEventListener('gpsContextValueEvent', function (e1) { 
        //some code here                        
    }, false);
```

My question is; in this code what is the purpose of the 'e1' within the function parameters? I should say that this JS file makes use of other JS scripts/modules/plugins and that 'gpsContextValueEvent' is a function in another file. Does it have something to do with that? Thanks so much and sorry for the stupid question.

Comment: I think that is a variable for `event` object. You have asked like you are referring a keyword `e1`.

Answer (score 2):

**It's a parameter that the event listener will get when this event is fired.**

What happens here is you tell the browser when `'gpsContextValueEvent'` occurs, a function specified after it (called `listener` in MDN) is called. And `e1` is the argument that will be given to this function by the browser (you can't control that).

How it should be processed is a matter of where do you pass this function (it's an *event handler* here), this should be documented with the function you're passing you handler into. In this case, with `addEventListener`, [according to MDN, `e1` will be an **event interface**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event).

I also have to note that this parameter is usually called `event` or similarly (`evt` in the link above). It doesn't matter what you call it in your own function as long as you refer to the same name (in your case `e1`), because it will still be the first argument and will contain the same thing. However, naming it `event` instead of `e1` could improve code readability which is a good thing.

Comment: `gpsContextValueEvent` sounds very much like a custom event type, so probably it is controlled by js how the argument looks like.

Comment: @Bergi You are right, I should have noticed that it's not a standard event. Those try to blend in with standard events though, so they **probably** behave the same way. Honestly, **I'm not sure** how it's done in the author's code, but I would add any custom arguments after the first one. I'm not an expert on this topic, I'd prefer not to add more mistakes to my answer. Someone more competent could reflect that by editing it.